# ARB_occlusion_query usage causing 'invalid enumerant' errors withing OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently working on a project where I'm utilizing the ARB_occlusion_query extension. I have the extension registered properly and I can generate the queries, I then start one and after rendering call the EndQuery function but this seems to give me the error of 'invalid enumerant'. I have checked the speqs here:
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/occlusion_query.txt

I am calling the EndQueries as follows:

```
glEndQuery( GL_SAMPLES_PASSED_ARB );
```

And all of this seems valid but it keeps giving me an error code stating 'invalid enumerant', error code 1280.

I've been adding error checking to every OpenGL call I make just to be sure the error is not comming from anywhere else and I have isolated it to this section. I generate the query as follows:

```
glGenQueries( size, (GLuint*)m_QueryID);
```

Where size is (for now) a hardcoded value 10 and the m_QueryID is a unsigned int array with again the size of 10.

The only place where things seem to go wrong is the glEndQuery call. It gives me 'invalid enumerant' in return. All the other calls like getting results, starting the query and in the end deleting them is all fine.

My loop is as follows:

```
glBeginQuery( GL_SAMPLES_PASSED_ARB, m_QueryID[0] ); 
*render some models here*
glEndQuery( GL_SAMPLES_PASSED_ARB );
```

And after that I will get the results, I am not doing anything at the moment because of the error I get on the glEndQuery call.

And according to the error codes in the speq it says:

> GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if target is not GL_SAMPLES_PASSED.

Which means I am not passing GL_SAMPLES_PASSED in there, which I am. I even tried without the ARB but of course no change, same thing still complaining about an invalid enumerant.

Comment: As a side note, either use the ARB extension or the core version, but don't mix non-ARB functions with ARB identifiers. Usually it doesn't make difference, but you never know. In fact, since occlusion queries are core since GL 1.5 (~10 years) you can just drop all this `ARB` rubbish.